# How to Add Linebreak to Postgres Text Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add a linebreak to a text object in rails.

Using rails 5.0 and postgres 9.4

```
some_text = "string sentence one"
some_text += #how do i add line break here
some_text = "string sentence two"
```

I've tried chr(10), '\n', \n, '/\n/' and /\n/

How would I add a line break to `some_text`?

**tl;dr**

Below is a loop that I am using in a controller to loop through attributes of an object and try to add a line break to it

```
@some_text ||= ""
object.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
    @some_text << attr_value.to_s + "\n"
end
```

When I display the @some_text object in a view, it has no line breaks. If I save the @some_text object into postgres, it still has no line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `"\n"` (with double quotes):

```
some_text = "string sentence one"
some_text << "\n"
some_text << "string sentence two"
```

If you want to output multiline string in irb or der Rails console use `puts`. Whereas `p` doesn't work, because it shows control characters instead.

It is worth noting that line break in HTML are usually not displayed in the rendered document. To translate new line characters in strings (`\n`) into visible HTML line breaks (`<br>`) there a several options:

- Translating the string (`string_with_linebreaks.gsub("\n", '<br>')`),
- use Rails' [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) text helper or a markdown parser,
- place the string into a `<pre>` block that usually (unless the default css is changed) will preserves both spaces and line breaks or
- declare a css rule like `white-space: pre-line` on the surrounding HTML tag.

Comment: You know I tried both in the console and a rails controller and it did not break the line. Rails console returns:  => "string sentence one\nstring sentence two"

Comment: In postgres it gets stored that way as well, not with a line break

Comment: How do you print to the console? It should work with `puts`, but not with `p`. How did you test in the controller? HTML doesn't show line breaks per default.

Comment: @HoosierCoder That's how the string will look when displayed as an `inspect` version, that is all non-printable or control characters *will* show up as things like `\n`. This is an old convention that's been adopted by many systems, including Postgres. What you see in this string form versus what you get when you print it will differ slightly.

Comment: I updated my question with details on how I use it in rails. You are right, if I use the console, and use `puts some_text` it does work. So, how would I get it to display in a database or a view, like it does with `puts`

Comment: @HoosierCoder You don't. You learn to live with it this way because that's what everyone who works with Postgres expects. If you don't like the way it looks, write a script that displays it the way you want.

Comment: @tadman, so something like store in an array or JSON in pg and loop thru in a view to show line by line?

Comment: Whatever suits your needs. If you have unique display requirements, which isn't unusual, you'll need to handle how to output it. In the console that means `puts`. In HTML that means converting `\n` to `<br>`.

Comment: Here's the html solution: `<p style="white-space: pre-line;">`